# R: Same object saved in different file formats and then re-imported takes different memory usage

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, parquet, file-format

Problem:

I have a dataset in R of several Gb and after some cleaning, I used arrow's parquet file format instead of csv for faster reading/writing and lesser disk size on my ssd.

When I tried to load it back in a fresh instance I found out that the same dataset takes different memory usage, even if the object.size of the data.frame is the same.

Shouldn't the object loaded in memory have the same size regardless of the original format?

What's the explanation for this behavior?

Example code below:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- nycflights13::flights


data.table::fwrite(df, "df.csv")

arrow::write_parquet(df, "df.parquet")

#Restart R and load df. Do a garbage collection and check memory usage and object.size

df <- data.table::fread("df.csv") %>% as.data.frame()

gc()

object.size(df)

#Restart R and load df. Do a garbage collection and check memory usage and object.size

df <- arrow::read_parquet("df.parquet")

gc()
```

The difference here is small but not zero. With the dataset I'm working on, the difference in memory allocated is a bigger, almost double.

Comment: How much difference do you see?  You can use `reprex::reprex()` to mingle output with your code, and then we could see what you're talking about.  Do you see the same reports if you call `gc()` twice in a row?  I don't.

Comment: and if you use `identical` to compare the two datasets after importing, do you get `TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

This discrepancy seems to come from comparing apples to pears. `data.table` imports tables in a different way than `read.csv` and `read_csv` (from `readr`). First of all it loads the data as a `data.table`, meanwhile `read_parquet` reads data into a `tibble`. `fread` further checks for integer columns and store these as integers while `read_parquet` stores them as `numeric`.

Looking into the objects we see clearly that `df` loaded with `fread` has several integer columns which are `numeric` for the alternative. Lets try converting these and compare the object sizes:

```
df <- data.table::fread("df.csv")
df2 <- arrow::read_parquet("df.parquet")
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(names(sapply(df, is.integer))[sapply(df, is.integer)], 
                .fns = as.integer))
pryr::object_size(df)  # 32,567,576 B
pryr::object_size(df2) # 2,700,824 B
pryr::object_size(df3) # 32,570,040 B
```

If we instead use `object.size` these values change and `df2` actually turns out to use more storage compared to `df`. This indicates `pryr` might not be capable of correctly locating the nuances of storage for `data.table`.

Further `data.table` adds additional effects in the background as it utilizes threads, which might account for the remaining discrepancy.